# Dependency-Driven random generator in C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding. I have some experience years ago with other languages, but I'm essentially starting fresh with C#. I'm trying to make a series of logic-driven random generators that will help me with my writing. The part about it being logic-driven is the kick in the pants. I've got an HTML/Javascript version working but I want to do it in C# and I'm stuck.

Essentially, the generator will randomly generate the first trait of whatever it is that I'm making. For example, maybe I'm running my random creature generator and the "Creature Type" is "Avian" (Birdlike). Based on THAT result, other features and traits would randomly generate. For example, it wouldn't say that the skin type is "membrane" for an Avian creature. If the creature has pointed teeth, it wouldn't show up with a diet of "vegetarian".

I was able to make a very basic random generator, however, I'm not sure this is the best way to go about it. Should I make this a List? An Array? Something else? Everything that I've searched online is explaining how to build a random number generator, which isn't what I need, or it's a simple list with no dependency logic built in. Aside from having an idea of what it should do, I don't know enough C# to get it. I'm not even sure I'm searching google with the right terms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean C++ or C#?

Comment: Apologies, I meant C#.

Comment: It might help to think about the data in terms of "domains".  For the *raptor* domain (e.g.), there are *n* characteristics for skin, *y* values legal for teeth, maybe only 2 choices for eyes etc.  After listing them, you basically have a collection of collections.  When you need to make a lizard, pick randomly from each pile of (legal) traits to make a new one.  You only have to be a little clever to get it to create a Lizard or Wombat object for you.

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp - Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I already have the logic tables or domains created. I'm not sure how to do it in C#. Should I make them as a Class? A list? An array? something else?  How should I link them together? Etc.

Comment: What you're describing can be modeled as a Markov process. I'll be publishing an article in my blog about ways to model Markov processes in C# next week, but you might want to read the 22 related blog posts that precede it for context.

Comment: Thanks, @EricLippert. I see the link on your profile. I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: I did something like this a view years ago. I was working for a company that dealt with Personally Identifiable Information and I needed to generate a large number of "people" with reasonable names, addresses, social security numbers, etc.  I simply created a small tool that, when given a list of strings, would use System.Random to pick one of them. The string lists were stored in text files (read in and cached at startup) and obtained by scraping inet sites.  Non-string data could mostly be generated from random integers; even SSNs, "9" concated with an 8 digit random number gives a good SSN.

Comment: I forgot to finish that off.  In your case, you'd need a set of string lists that formed a simple tree: If it's _Avian_ use the _AvianSkinType_ list.

Answer (score 1):

All right, let's go step-by-step.

> Based on THAT result, other features and traits would randomly generate.

OK, so you need a function: `ISet<T> Choices(T instance);` responsible for providing a set (i.e. list with no duplicated elements and internal implementation optimised for checks like `bool Contains(T instance)`) of next possible options. The options provided **must** take into consideration the essence of given `T instance` and provide only valid options such that predator won't be a vegetarian.

Then you need `T AnyOf(IEnumerable<T> options)` function that randonly picks up any element contained within a given `IEnumerable<T>`. Obviously, it gonna model non-determenism.

Eventually, you have to match those such that they form a chain `T Generate()` that is self-sufficient to make a fresh valid instance.

Please note, generally you'll deal with different `T`'s. There is no implicit assumption that all of them are interrelated. It's up to you to model your instances richly enough to be able to apply the sketch I drew above.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, Sereja. I'm going to have to Google what you just said so that I understand it, but at least now I have some idea of what to look for.

Comment: @JohnathanClayborn, just try to be more concrete next time you'll come back to the SO; otherwise people won't be able to help you out.

Comment: how do you propose I be more concrete? The first thing I literally said was "I'm new to coding". it's very difficult to explain something in technical terms when you don't know what the technical term is. I'm trying to learn, and I thought SO would be a good place to ask questions so that I can learn. Instead, people want to downvote my question because I'm a noob and put C++ instead of C#. If I knew enough of the technical langue to describe my question in more detail, I wouldn't have needed to ask it in the first place.

Comment: @JohnathanClayborn, just provide more code and try to specify exact place(s), where you feel uncertain and why keeping noise away: in your case, no html is needed, nor the "Authoritarian - The Government knows what is best for the people". That's the point: remove everything, except was makes you stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I thought that having some context would be helpful for people to understand. I'll make things more concise.